# 'NSString' is not a subtype of 'UILabel'

Tags: swift

I am developing a simple `tableView` with `Custom Cell` and in that when user click on any row it's navigate to the next `DetailViewController` and that `detailViewController` displays a information and my code is:

Iteams.swift

```
class Iteam {

var name = "name"
var time = "Time"
var imageName = "blank"

init(name : String, time : String, imageName : String){

    self.name = name
    self.time = time
    self.imageName = imageName
    }
}
```

DetailViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var iteamImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var iteamName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var iteamPrepTime: UILabel!

var nameStr : String = String()
var prepTime : Int = Int()
var iteamImageName : String = String()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.iteamName.text = nameStr
    self.iteamPrepTime.text = String(prepTime)
    self.iteamImage.image = UIImage(named: iteamImageName)
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

var arrayOfIteams : [Iteam] = [Iteam]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.setOfIteams()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
func setOfIteams(){

    var iteam1 = Iteam(name: "Egg Benedict", time: "00:10", imageName: "egg_benedict.jpg")
    var iteam2 = Iteam(name: "Mushroom Risotto", time: "00:20", imageName: "mushroom_risotto.jpg")
    var iteam3 = Iteam(name: "Full Breakfast", time: "00:30", imageName: "full_breakfast.jpg")
    var iteam4 = Iteam(name: "Hamburger", time: "00:20", imageName: "hamburger.jpg")
    var iteam5 = Iteam(name: "Ham and Egg Sandwich", time: "00:10", imageName: "ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg")
    var iteam6 = Iteam(name: "Creme Brelee", time: "00:20", imageName: "creme_brelee.jpg")
    var iteam7 = Iteam(name: "White Chocolate Donut", time: "00:30", imageName: "white_chocolate_donut.jpg")
    var iteam8 = Iteam(name: "Starbucks Coffee", time: "00:20", imageName: "starbucks_coffee.jpg")
    var iteam9 = Iteam(name: "Vegetable Curry", time: "00:10", imageName: "vegetable_curry.jpg")
    var iteam10 = Iteam(name: "Instant Noodle with Egg", time: "00:20", imageName: "instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg")
    var iteam11 = Iteam(name: "Noodle with BBQ Pork", time: "00:10", imageName: "noodle_with_bbq_pork.jpg")
    var iteam12 = Iteam(name: "Japanese Noodle with Pork", time: "00:10", imageName: "japanese_noodle_with_pork.jpg")
    var iteam13 = Iteam(name: "Green Tea", time: "00:20", imageName: "green_tea.jpg")
    var iteam14 = Iteam(name: "Thai Shrimp Cake", time: "00:10", imageName: "thai_shrimp_cake.jpg")
    var iteam15 = Iteam(name: "Angry Birds Cake", time: "00:30", imageName: "angry_birds_cake.jpg")
    var iteam16 = Iteam(name: "Ham and Cheese Panini", time: "00:10", imageName: "ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg")

    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam1)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam2)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam3)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam4)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam5)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam6)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam7)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam8)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam9)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam10)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam11)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam12)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam13)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam14)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam15)
    arrayOfIteams.append(iteam16)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

    return arrayOfIteams.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell : CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as CustomCell

    let food = arrayOfIteams[indexPath.row]
    cell.setCell(food.name, prepTimeText: food.time, imageName: (food.imageName))
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    let iteam = arrayOfIteams[indexPath.row]


    var detailViewController : DetailViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DetailViewController") as DetailViewController
    detailViewController.nameStr = iteam.name
    detailViewController.iteamPrepTime = iteam.time      // here I got an error
    detailViewController.iteamImageName = iteam.imageName
    self.presentViewController(detailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Other `nameStr` and `iteamImageName` are working fine.

Any Solution for this?

Comment: Well, yeah: You're trying to assign a String, team.time, to a variable of type UILabel, iteamPrepTime. That would be an error. Did you mean to assign it to the UILabel's `text` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is called 'prepTime' but you now assign directly to the UILabel itemPrepTime which is not yet available (the view is not loaded yet). You have to assign the value to your variable and assign it to the UILabel.text it in the ViewDidLoad (as you do already).

So:

```
detailViewController.iteamPrepTime = iteam.time      // here I got an error
```

Should be:

```
detailViewController.prepTime = iteam.time
```

Additional note: Try to have some consistency in you variable names. Why did you include the iteam prefix in the variable iteamImageName? This causes confusion, because the UILabel outlets do also have this prefix. Just using imageName as variable would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need to do

```
detailViewController.iteamPrepTime.text = iteam.time
```

You were basically setting the value of a UILabel object as a String object. Set the text property of the UILabel instead.

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: It is giving me error like : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: I tried it and I also tried iteamPrepTime? but as it becomes nil nothing prints out on detailViewController in label.

Comment: Has your detailViewController been instantiated properly? Does it have a non-nil value?

Comment: yeah its initiate properly and nameStr and iteamImageName is displayed but iteamprepTime is shown as 0